# Django allauth example [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have the following error when I run django allauth example and it tries to send an email:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
raise err
error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Under OS X 10.9.1

Comment: Related error message: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` would be solved by setting up email server as shown in the accepted answer. - Added details so that this shows up in Google searches

Comment: My problem with django-allauth is that when i try the github project, i migrate ok but all the time says that: "You have 26 unapplied migration(s)."... the same all the time.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

From [allauth documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#when-i-sign-up-i-run-into-connectivity-errors-connection-refused-et-al):

> **When I sign up I run into connectivity errors (connection refused et al)**
>
> You probably have not got an e-mail (SMTP) server running on the
> machine you are developing on. Therefore, allauth is unable to send
> verification mails.
>
> You can work around this by adding the following line to settings.py:
>
> EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend' This
> will avoid the need for an SMTP server as e-mails will be printed to
> the console. For more information, please refer to:
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-backend

Comment: +1 Thanks for this. Saved me hours of frustration. That error message does not really do justice. However after looking at your post, I went back and saw the stacktrace. Notice something about SMTP there.

Comment: The email does not get sent though, it only appears in the console.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively if you have a social sign up, you probably do not require verification email so you can just add `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'` to your settings. This will automatically solve the problem.